# bash Tab autocompletion breaks on using 'which'

Tags: bash, terminal, autocomplete

Bash Tab autocompletion with cd command breaks if use **which** command inside a custom function like (I am overriding type to have a custom functionality)

```
type(){
      which "$1"
}
```

with error when trying Tab with cd command

```
bash: warning: programmable_completion: cd: possible retry loop
```

but doesnt break if I use any command other than **which** inside the function

```
type(){
      echo "$1"
}
```

Comment: I don't understand, how is this linked to completion for `cd`?

Comment: @BenjaminW. I changed the function name to type and the issue comes

Comment: How? Is it if you try to tab-complete the function name, an argument to the function, what?

Comment: As an aside, `type` isn't a good function name as it's the name of a [Bash builtin](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#index-type).

Comment: @BenjaminW. I am trying to override type with extra functionality